# retrofit com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit

they are new to Retrofit and I am trying to get data from a JSON using the ID, with the post method, but I throw this arror.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlXwL.png)

This is the JSON I'm trying to consume`

```
[{"idPlakas":"6","latitud":"19.681984","longitud":"-101.171496","titulo":"markador"}]
```

Here is my post method making the request by ID.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/Cprincipal/obtener_carro/")
void obtCarro(@Field("idPlakas") int idPlakas, Callback<Carro> callback);
```

I perform the following code to receive the object and the information that it has, and this same madarla to another method that would create a marker.
But when running my application does not enter that method and I get the error.

```
public void actualizarMarcador() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter =  new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://192.168.1.70/formularios").build();

    CoordenadaServicio serv = restAdapter.create(CoordenadaServicio.class);

    serv.obtCarro(placaM, new Callback<Carro>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Carro carro, Response response) {

            if (carroObjeto!=null){
                carroObjeto=null;
            }
            carroObjeto = new Carro();
            carroObjeto.setIdPlakas(carro.getIdPlakas());
            carroObjeto.setLongitud(carro.getLongitud());
            carroObjeto.setLatitud(carro.getLatitud());
            carroObjeto.setTitulo(carro.getTitulo());



            generarMarker(carroObjeto);
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("mapa", " failed "+ String.valueOf(error));
        }
    });
}
```

this is my class

```
class Carro {

@SerializedName("idPlakas")
private int idPlakas;
public int getIdPlakas() {
    return idPlakas;
}

public void setIdPlakas(int idPlakas) {
    this.idPlakas = idPlakas;
}

@SerializedName("latitud")
private Double latitud;
public Double getLatitud() {
    return latitud;
}

public void setLatitud(Double latitud) {
    this.latitud = latitud;
}

@SerializedName("longitud")
private Double longitud;
public Double getLongitud() {
    return longitud;
}

public void setLongitud(Double longitud) {
    this.longitud = longitud;
}

@SerializedName("titulo")
private String titulo;
public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}
```

}

Comment: Let's see the Carro class, it's probably incorrect.

Comment: Hola @Nasch Agregar clase a mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Callback` expects a single `Carro` object.

```
Callback<Carro> callback
```

but the response you have posted is a Json array (note the square brackets)

```
[{"idPlakas":"6","latitud":"19.681984","longitud":"-101.171496","titulo":"markador"}]
```

so you need to change your callback to expect a `List<Carro>`